# Azure Functions - local.settings.json vs launchSettings.json

Tags: azure, function, .net-core

Recently I am trying to refactor an Azure Functions project I have, adding dev and prod environments. What should I choose to go with? `local.settings.json` or `launchSettings.json` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem with the use of binding expressions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-expressions---app-settings

Using debug profiles with environment settings and bindings like

```
[Table("%feedbacksTableName%")] CloudTable feedbacksTable
```

MS says that `%env-var-name-here%` can be set through `local.settings.json` or environment vars.